# http_response_code не работает

Tags: php, nginx

index.php выглядит так:

```
<?php
http_response_code(405);
die();
```

В хроме вижу `Status Code:200 OK`. Из скрипта вижу, что код устанавливается. Но почему в браузер все равно приходит `200`?

Вот что есть:

```
Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u1 x86_64
nginx/1.10.1
PHP 5.4.45-0
```

В настройке сервера, к сожалению, совсем не силён, даже не могу предположить куда копать. Гугл тоже не помог.

Comment: `<?php header('Status: 405', TRUE, 405); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Цитата с [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.http-response-code.php#refsect1-function.http-response-code-returnvalues)

> mixed http_response_code ([ int $response_code ] )
>       ....
>       Если response_code задан, то будет возвращен предыдущий код статуса.
>       Если response_code не задан, то будет возвращен текущий код статуса.
>       Оба этих значения будут по умолчанию 200 если используются в окружении веб-сервера.

Пример [оттуда же](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.http-response-code.php#refsect1-function.http-response-code-examples):

```
Пример #1 Использование http_response_code() в окружении веб-сервера
// Берем текущий код и устанавливаем новый
var_dump(http_response_code(404));

// Берем новый код
var_dump(http_response_code());

Результат выполнения данного примера:

int(200)
int(404)
```

Comment: Я понимаю, нужно использовать решение из комментария?

Comment: смотрите ответ.